# Ocaml implementation advice for an algorithm on sets

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, set

I am having problems for converting following algo in ocaml To implement this algorithm i used `Set.Make(String)` functor actualy in and out are 2 functions Can any one give me percise code help in ocaml for following

This is actually [Algo for Live Variables[PDF]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4120/2009fa/lectures/lec20-fa09.pdf) ..Help would be appreciated greatly

```
for all n, in[n] = out[n] = Ø
w = { set of all nodes }
repeat until w empty
    n = w.pop( )
    out[n] = ∪  n’ ∈ succ [n] in[n’]
    in[n] = use[n] ∪ (out[n] — def [n])
    if change to in[n],
        for all predecessors m of n, w.push(m)
end
```

Comment: Sets do not support `pop`. You must first understand what data structure is `w` in the pseudocode before you can translate it to Caml.

Comment: i know for pop i will be using Queue module . All i am troubled in is tranformation of logic so if you can help me transforming that into logic will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

```
for all n, in[n] = out[n] = Ø
    w = { set of all nodes }
    repeat until w empty
    n = w.pop( )
    out[n] = ∪  n’ ∈ succ [n] in[n’]
    in[n] = use[n] ∪ (out[n] — def [n])
    if change to in[n],
    for all predecessors m of n, w.push(m)
end
```

It's hard for me to tell what is exactly going on here. I think there is some alignment issues with your text --`repeat until w empty` should be repeating the next 5lines, right? And how are in and out functions, they look like arrays to me? Aside from those deficiencies I'll tackle some general rules I have followed.

I've had to translate a number of numerical methods in C and Fortran algorithms to functional languages and I have some suggestions for you.

0) Define the datatypes being used. This will really help you with the next step (spoiler: looking for functional constructs). Once you know the datatypes you can more accurately define the functional constructs you will eventually apply.

1) Look for functional constructs. fold, recursion, and maps, and when to use them. For example, the `for all predecessors m` is a fold (unsure if that it would fold over a tree or list, but none-the-less, a fold). `While` loops are a good place for recursion --but don't worry about making it a tail call, you can modify the parameters later to adhere to those requirements. Don't worry about being 100% pure. Remove enough impure constructs (references or arrays) to get a feel for the algorithm in a functional way.

2) Write *any* part of the algorithm that you can. Leaving functions blank, add dummy values, and just implement what you know --then you can ask SO better, more informed questions.

3) Re-write it. There is a good chance you missed some functional constructs or used an array or reference where you now realize you can use a list or set or by passing an accumulator. You may have defined a list, but later you realize you cannot randomly access it (well, it would be pretty detrimental to), or it needs to be traversed forward and back (a good place for a zipper). Either way, when you finally get it you'll know, and you should have a huge ear-to-ear grin on your face.